# Read line by line and get the previous and the next lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read a file line by line and get every current, previous and next line. Eg:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

What I'd like is:

```
None, line1, line2
line1, line2, line3
line2, line3, line4
```

Here's my attempt:

```
previous = None
with open(filename) as f:
   for line in f:
      line = line.strip()
      previous_line = previous
      previous = line
      next_line = next(f)
      print(previous_line, line, next_line)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next(f)` consumes the next line, each line can only be read once, so you need to reorder how you read lines. This should work

```
with open(filename) as f:
    previous = None
    current = next(f).strip()
    for line in f:
        line=line.strip()
        print(previous, current, line)
        previous = current
        current = line
```

Output:

```
None line1 line2
line1 line2 line3
line2 line3 line4
```

Comment: Nearly identical to mine, but two minutes faster :P

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you're encountering is that `next(f)` iterates the file position, so for each iteration of the `for` loop, two lines are actually being read.

You can accomplish this by changing your approach slightly. Instead of `line` being the center element, you should have `line` refer to the last element, and maintain `previous-previous` as well as `previous`.

```
prevprev = None
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    # Read the first line before the loop
    prev = f.readline().strip()
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        print(prevprev, prev, line)
        prevprev = prev
        prev = line
```

Output:

```
None line1 line2
line1 line2 line3
line2 line3 line4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [None, None, None]
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines[0] = lines[1]
        lines[1] = lines[2]
        lines[2] = line.strip()
        if lines[1] and lines[2]:
            print(', '.join([str(l) for l in lines]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple for loop:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [None]+f.read().split('\n')

size = 3
for i in range(len(data)-(size-1)):
    print(data[i:i+size])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use slices of lists:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    xs = [None]*3
    for x in f:
        xs = xs[1:] + [x]
        print xs
```

outputs:

```
[None, None, 'line1\n']
[None, 'line1\n', 'line2\n']
['line1\n', 'line2\n', 'line3\n']
['line2\n', 'line3\n', 'line4\n']
['line3\n', 'line4\n', 'line5\n']
```

Cleaning up to match your exact output format:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    xs = ['None']*2 + [f.next().strip()]
    for x in f:
        xs = xs[1:] + [x.strip()]
        print ', '.join(xs)
```

outputs:

```
None, line1, line2
line1, line2, line3
line2, line3, line4
line3, line4, line5
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use unpacking:

```
data = [None]+[i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')] 
def group_data(d):
  while len(d) > 2:
    a, b, c, *d1 = d
    yield [a, b, c]
    d = [b, c]+d1

print(list(group_data(s)))
```

Output:

```
[[None, 'line1', 'line2'], ['line1', 'line2', 'line3'], ['line2', 'line3', 'line4']]
```