# How do I process the next line when looping through the current lines?

Tags: python, readline

Having a go at converting a vba macro to python. 1st step in python so don't throw stones if so obvious.

```
Reading a text file 
processing each line
if the line contains a keyword 
    I want to process the next 2 lines 
    (which have the data I need to extract)
```

How do I select the line i+1 & i+2 if the current (valid) line is i?

Thanks

Comment: Practically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to get you started:

```
with open('path/to/file') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'keyword' in line:
            line = f.readline() # line i+1 
            line = f.readline() # line i+2
```

Don't forget to substitute `path/to/file` and `keyword` with actual values (and do keep the surrounding `''`)

Comment: Thanks. make sense now. Already "expanded" by adding:- TheInputFile.readline().strip() for the 2 lines and I need and joining them for data extraction

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do that in python:

```
with open ('text.txt') as text_file :
    for line in text_file :
        if 'keyword' in line :
            first_line = text_file.readline ()
            second_line = text_file.readline ()

print (first_line, second_line)
```